# How can I embed a console app's output into my X11 desktop?

Tags: networking, desktop, cinnamon, conky

I'd like to view [NetHogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/) output on my desktop.

For example, do any `Conky` or `applets` on Cinnamon exist, so I don't need to have a terminal open all the time?

Comment: A search for "embed terminal into desktop" comes up with some promising results. Have you tried any of them and found any particular problem? What desktop environment are you on?